# Proof $X_n\xrightarrow{D}X$ and $Y_n \xrightarrow{P}0$ then $X_n + Y_n \xrightarrow{D}X$

Tags: statistics

I am having trouble proving this theorem.

I know that I am given
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }Pr[X_n<x] = Pr[X<x]$$ 
and 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }Pr[|Y_n| > \epsilon] = 0, \quad\forall\epsilon>0$$
where I have to show that 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }Pr[X_n+Y_n<t]=Pr[X<t] \qquad(1)$$

Editted:

I know that I have to use the squeeze theorem, but I am not too strong in limit problems...

I cannot use Slutsky's Theorem because I am actually trying to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: use the following: $\{X_n+Y_n \leq t\} \subset \{X_n \leq t+\epsilon\} \cup \{|Y_n| >\epsilon\}$ and $\{X_n \leq t -\epsilon\} \subset \{X_n+Y_n \leq t\} \cup \{|Y_n| >\epsilon\}$

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand how the statements are true...

Comment: @hyg17 Suppose $X_n+Y_n \leq t$. Either $|Y_n| >\epsilon$ or $|Y_n| \leq \epsilon$. In the second case $X_n =(X_n+Y_n)-Y_n \leq t+\epsilon$ because $-Y_n \leq |Y_n| \leq \epsilon$. This proves the first part in my answer and the second part is similar.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to work on it.

Comment: I understand that $X_n+Y_n \le t$ then $X_n \le t+ \epsilon$ is true, but why would the set of ${X_n+Y_n \le t}$ be a subset of $X_n \le t + \epsilon \cup |Y_n| \le \epsilon$?  I am sorry I am not good at sets.

Comment: To show that $A \subset B\cup C$ take $a \in A$. Consider the cases $a \in C$ and  $a \notin C$. If the first case we already know that $a \in B \cup C$. In the second case you try to show that $a \in B$ so that $a \in B \cup C$. This is what I have done.

Comment: Hello, Mr. Murthy.  Would it be okay if I ask you if I did some of it right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Slutsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) theorem, i.e., as $Y_n$ converges in probability to a constant $c=0$, then 
$$
X_n + Y_n \xrightarrow{D} X+c=X.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You should have the following for  $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$

$X = Pr\{X_n\} \leq Pr\{X_n + Y_{n}\} \leq Pr\{X_{n}\} + Pr \{Y_{n}\} = X +0 = X $

so take the extreme and is valid

$X \leq Pr\{X_n + Y_{n}\} \leq X $

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way for the record (uses too much theory, because -  as noted above -  problem can be done directly):

$$E[e^{it (X_n + Y_n)}] = E[e^{it X_n}] + \underset{(*)}{\underbrace{E[e^{itX_n}(e^{itY_n} -1)]}}.$$

$|(*)|\le E[ |e^{itY_n} -1|] \to 0$ by dominated convergence (note that convergence in probability is sufficient for the conclusion of DCT to hold).